# javascript this.value doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

sorry for asking that stupid:D However what did i do wrong here?

html:

```
<div onclick="prompt()" value="test">test</div>
```

javascript:

```
function prompt() {

    var error = this.value;
    alert("sdsd");

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `div`s don't have `value`s, they have `textContent`s. Also, this is not jQuery

Comment: Remember that "prompt" is a function that exists already in javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, `<div>`s don't have a `value` attribute, so `.value` won't work.  Second, you should *not* use inline JavaScript.

What you should do is:

```
<div id="test" value="test">test</div>
```

Then:

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
        // You need to get the attribute from the element
        var error = $(this).attr('value');
    });
});
```

If you *must* use inline events, then you need to *pass* the element to the `prompt()` function.  The problem is that it doesn't know what `this` is.  This is why you should bind the event as shown above.  Anyway, you can also do:

```
<div onclick="prompt(this)" value="test">test</div>
```

Then:

```
function prompt(ele){
    // You can't use `.value` because `<div>`s
    // don't have a value property
    var error = ele.getAttribute('value');
}
```

P.S. May I also suggest using `data-*` attributes for this instead of *invalid* attributes?

```
<div id="test" data-value="test">test</div>
```

Then:

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
        var error = $(this).data('value');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of `this` depends on how the function that it appears in was called.

When the browser calls the onclick function from the event trigger, `this` is the input.

When you call `prompt()`, because you provided no context and you are no in strict mode, `this` is the `window`.

You need to explicitly pass the value.

```
onclick="prompt.call(this)"
```

Better yet, don't use intrinsic event attributes in the first place. They mix your HTML and logic and have a whole collection of gotchas to go with them.

Then you have a second problem.

Div elements don't have values. Only inputs and other form controls do. You would need to use `.getAttribute("value")` instead of `.value` … but that still leaves your HTML invalid (as well as inappropriate - div elements aren't designed to be interacted with, they give no visual indication that they should be clicked on, and they won't receive the focus should the user not be using a mouse or other pointing device anyway).

You should use a control designed to be interacted with.

Finally, `prompt` is a built in function, so you should avoid overwriting it and pick a different name instead.

```js
function show_value(event) {
    var value = this.value;
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", show_value);
```

```html
<button type="button" value="test">test</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Div does not have value attribute.

If you need to get the value inside div element you can do it by innerHTML property.

```
function prompt() {

    var error = this.innerHTML; // OR this.getAttribute("value");

}
```