# loading variable page into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'am new JS I now c# and Java 
I can try learning php and js ajax Can you help me pls

```js
function divload()
{
    $('#middle').load('page.php');
}

and 

 <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:divload()"  >new</a>
```

this function is very good but Can I do this

> 

```js
function divload($page)
{
    $('#orta').load('$page');
}

<a class="nav-link" href="javascript:divload("new.php")"  >new page to div</a>
```

Comment: Yes you can, just need a little change. See the almost the identical problem here  [javascript this.value doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518960/javascript-this-value-doesnt-work)

Comment: Yes, just change the `$page` to `page` and change your double quotes (`"`) on the href to single quotes (`'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
function divload(page)
{
    $('#orta').load(page);
}
```

and

```
<a class="nav-link" href="javascript:divload('new.php')"  >new page to div</a>
```

Comment: ohh thanks . I don't know how can i use variables this "" or '' , $,  but your answer very good my minds thank you :)

Comment: You are most welcome